# WordPress Remove Excerpt Filters

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to strip the surrounding tags that are put out by default for the_excerpt();

I've tried the following...

```
<?php remove_filter('the_excerpt', 'wpautop'); ?>
<p class='test'><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
```

and I've tried...

```
<?php $formatted = remove_all_filters('the_excerpt', the_excerpt()); ?>
<p class='test'><?php echo $formatted ?></p>
```

I'm looking to produce this...

```
<p class='test'>the excerpt text <a href='http://continuereadinglink'>etc.</a></p>
```

But instead WordPress outputs this...

```
<p class='test'></p>
<p class='default-align'>the excerpt text <a href='http://continuereadinglink'>etc.</a></p>
```

I have actually found a workaround here http://aaronrussell.co.uk/legacy/improving-wordpress-the_excerpt/, but it basically involves replacing the excerpt function, and I would rather avoid this since I just want to strip the filters out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML paragraph tags don't support nested structure. Try to surround the excerpt with block elements such as DIV

You may try this option:

```
<p class="test"><?php echo strip_tags(get_the_excerpt()) ?></p>
```

Comment: Ah yeah of course, I should have realised that. Would still like to strip the 'default-align' class out though by removing the filters.

Comment: Try <?php remove_filter('the_excerpt', 'default-align'); ?>

Comment: No that didn't work :-(

I tried

`<?php remove_filter('the_excerpt', 'default-align'); ?>`
`<div class='test'><?php echo the_excerpt(); ?></div>`

Comment: Aahhh I'm such an idiot, it wasn't working because I had a piece of jQuery assigning the class of default-align to all p tags. Sorry to waste your time!